# T12 soldering station problem

Tags: microcontroller, relay, switching, thermocouple

[image]I am trying to make a “cheap” t12 based soldering station. However there is a problem. Since T12 tips have the thermocouple and the heating coil in series, you have to turn the driving MOSFET off, read the temperature and based on that turn the coil on or off.

Now I am using a MAX6675 IC to measure the T12’s thermocouples temperature. Its easier to use (using a library) and skips the calibration part for me that I would have to go for if I choose the op-amp alternative.

So coming back to my actual problem, turning the MOSFET off for measuring the temperature is no-brainer, but the problem is when I turn the MOSFET on. Since the negative of thermocouple is permanently grounded, the current flows through the MAX6675 too, in contrast to the T12 tip. I have tried several different things for example relays to switch between the Vcc (24 V) and positive of the MAX6675 pin. But since I have to measure temperature quickly, that is no way to go.

I also tried to manipulate the negative connection to momentarily cut the power out(negative going to MAX6675 from the tip) using a NPN BJT but that didn't work out either. I want something like a relay that completely blocks the voltages to one another but obviously it's not implementable.

I am an intermediate in electronics so any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: A schematic of what you have so far would be handy. Solid state relays, aka analogue switches, are readily available, as long as the voltages / currents are under control. Did I say 'handy'? I meant 'absolutely required'. I don't imagine anyone is going to try reading your mind through the description you've provided, I certainly won't.

Comment: Oops certainly forgot to do that. Since i originally didn't design the circuit “yet” i did not add it. But drew a rough estimate where i am stuck right now.

Comment: The IRF9540N is a P-channel MOSFET, which makes sense in this application and is appropriately connected here, but I thought it was wrong at first because you've drawn it as an incorrectly-connected N-channel MOSFET in your schematic.

Comment: Well the thing that needs to be done is either one of the two wires going to max 6675(preferentially vcc) to be temporarily cut off while the MOSFET is turned on.all the problem lies there. :)

Comment: Why are you powering the T12 like that? What's wrong with grounding the electrode that you are switching 24 V to? Then the thermocouple connection is grounded, and you only have to kill VCC to the heater to be able to read it.

Comment: Actually, now that I look at it more closely, I'm a little concerned about that IRF9540N. The absolute maximum gate voltage rating is ±20 V, and you're operating at exactly that. You should probably limit the gate voltage somehow so you don't blow your transistors.

Comment: @Neil_UK Would that make a difference? My understanding is that the problem is exceeding the MAX6675's ratings when the heater is *on*, not that there are any problems when the heater is *off*.

Comment: A relay to switch the pin out of circuit isn't as hard as you might think: a Coto 3600 series relay could be used. They have 0.75 ms operate time and 0.1 ms release time, so the timing isn't too bad, the lifetime rating is 5e8 operations, and they're low thermal EMF so they don't interfere with thermocouple readings very much. But there might be a good way to do this with solid-state switching; I'm just not too confident when it comes to switching thermocouples.

Comment: It might be easier to use a different series of iron tips that don't use the same two contacts for both power and thermocouple, though. I've seen a few hobbyists making their own soldering station using the tips from Weller's RTM series, which have a four-wire power/data interface that uses a standard 3.5 mm TRRS connector (which might not be the best choice, but at least it means the connectors are cheap).

Comment: Well the good thing about t12 tips is that they are amazingly cheap. And their availability(with different tip shapes) is also widespread. And third point being their heat up time, you blink and it has already reached half its desired temperature. But even with all these good features, it comes with its major drawback(if you are diy’ing) as mentioned in this thread. There are other options too like the c45’s and similar. They are not in series like this one, but they do share one common point too, so total of three pins.

Comment: The complete units are pretty cheap, so I would get one of them to see how they work then think about how you could do something ‘better’. As well, the circuits are well documented and open source firmware available on the interwebs so the path is well trodden.